# VW GOLF MK4 Doors won’t open from inside or outside

Tags: golf, locks, door

I have just replaced my front passenger door actuator as the door was deadlocked shut. The door now unlocks with the key fob, however neither the inside or outside handles work and the door still seems to be deadlocked and I’m back where I started! Can anyone suggest what might be the problem?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: The inside handle should open in any case, check the cable running from the handle to the lock mechanism, if the handle feels too easy it is probably the cable base disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Mechanics SE!

It is possible that the wiring to the actuator is faulty.  You can disconnect the multi-way plug and apply 12 volts to pins 1 and 2 on the locking module (+ve to pin 2). You only need to apply voltage for a couple of seconds.  This ought to pop the lock, if not it's possible that the new actuator is indeed deadlocked.

If you can pop the lock in this way, it may be that the loom is pinched somewhere or that a fuse is blown.  However, the fact that the other locks open on the remote would suggest that the problem is confined to your front passenger door.